# Password checker containing many conditional statements

Tags: python, security

Can this be shortened/improved? I'm trying to make a password checker in Python.

Could the `if`s be put into a `for` loop?  If so, how?

```
pw = input("Enter password to test: ")

caps = sum(1 for c in pw if c.isupper())
lower = sum(1 for c in pw if c.islower())
nums = sum(1 for c in pw if c.isnumeric())

scr = ['weak', 'medium', 'strong']
r = [caps, lower, nums]


if len(pw) < 6:
    print("too short") 
elif len(pw) > 12:
    print("too long")

if caps >= 1:
    if lower >= 1:
        if nums >= 1:
            print(scr[2])
        elif nums < 1:
            print("your password is " + scr[1])
    elif lower < 1:
        print("your password strength is " + scr[0])
elif caps < 1:
    print("your password strength is " + scr[1])
```

Comment: the code works from the looks of Gareth's answer, but I agree that your knowledge of Password strength is lacking.  Note: [Password Strength](http://xkcd.com/936/)

Answer (score 16):

```
Enter password to test: premaintenance disdainful hayloft seer
too long
your password strength is medium

Enter password to test: NXJCWGGDVQZO
your password strength is weak

Enter password to test: Password1
strong
```

Your knowledge of password strength is: weak.

#### Explanation

[Password strength](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password_strength) is normally measured in "[bits of entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_entropy)" — the idea being that if a password has been picked randomly from a pool of similar passwords of size *N*, then its entropy is log<sub>2</sub>*N* bits.

The first password I tried above was picked using a [method suggested by Randall Munroe](http://xkcd.com/936/), like this:

```
>>> words = list(open('/usr/share/dict/words'))
>>> import random
>>> random.SystemRandom().shuffle(words)
>>> print(' '.join(w.strip() for w in words[:4]))
premaintenance disdainful hayloft seer
```

Its entropy can be calculated like this:

```
>>> from math import log
>>> l = len(words)
>>> log(l * (l - 1) * (l - 2) * (l - 3), 2)
71.39088438576361
```

This is a strong password—a cracker that tried a billion such passwords a second would take on average about 50,000 years to find it.

The second password is also strong, but not as good as the first. I generated it like this:

```
$ </dev/random base64 | tr -cd A-Z | head -c 12
NXJCWGGDVQZO
```

Its entropy is 12 × log<sub>2</sub>26 = 56.4 bits.

The third password is, of course, the weakest. `password1` is about the 600th most common password ([according to Mark Burnett, here](https://xato.net/passwords/more-top-worst-passwords/)) and the initial capital letter is a common substitution that [password cracking programs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password_cracking) know all about.

Comment: that was kind of harsh. but I agree.

Comment: Judging from the last one, this code needs *emergency* improvement.

Answer (score 3):

Gareth's answer is correct and shows the real issues with what you are trying to achieve.

For the sake of learning more, let's review the actual code.

**What is good**

- Your code is simple and easy to understand.
- You are using `sum`, `isupper`, `islower` and `isnumeric` properly.

**What can be improved**

- Don't repeat yourself :

You don't need to do something like :

```
if condition:
    foo
elif not condition:
    bar
```

Just write :

```
if condition:
    foo
else:
    bar
```

Also, you don't need to repeat `print("your password strength is " + whatever)`.

The corresponding snippet can be written :

```
if caps >= 1:
    if lower >= 1:
        if nums >= 1:
            strength = scr[2]
        else:
            strength = scr[1]
    else:
        strength = scr[0]
else:
    strength = scr[1]
print("your password strength is " + scr[1])
```

- Keep things simple :

Also, because of the way Python evaluates integers as boolean, you can write the conditions : `if caps:`, `if lower` and `if nums`.

The `r` list is not used, get rid of it.

In a "normal" password checker, I guess it would be possible to factorise the different possible cases on the different criteria to make your code more concise. Here, I have troubles trying to see a logic behind the different cases you are considering. Why would a lower case password be `medium` no matter the other criteria while a pure upper case password would be `weak`...